# Renaming Worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with renaming a worksheet in VBA.

I'm writing a Sub that needs to check if there is a worksheet in the workbook that has a specific name, and if there isn't then make a new sheet with this name. 
I get the runtime error 1004 application defined or object defined error. I'm hoping anyone can help me. Here is my code:

> ```
> Dim ws As Worksheet 
> Dim ArrayElement As Variant 
> Dim Current_Tabs(1 To 10) As String 
>
> NumberNewTab = 1 
> Tab_Name_Current_Game = Echt_team1 + "vs. " + Echt_team2
>
> For Each ws In Worksheets 'For every worksheet in this workbook
>   Found = False 
>   For Each ArrayElement In Current_Tabs array
>       If Tab_Name_Current_Game = ArrayElement Then 
>       Worksheets(ws).Activate
>       Worksheets.Select
>       Found = True
>       End If
>       Next ArrayElement
>
>       If Found = False Then 
>          Worksheets.Add
>          Sheets(1).Name = Tab_Name_Current_Game **'Here I get the error**
>          Current_Tabs(NumberNewTab) = Tab_Name_Current_Game
>          NumberNewTab = NumberNewTab + 1
>       End If Next ws
> ```

If I use `Sheets(1).Name = "Test"` then I don't run into errors. I don't get why this would be a problem for VBA. Hoping someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: What does this Echt_team1 + "vs. " + Echt_team2 equate to on the first run ?

Comment: You should concatenate strings by using ampersands. `Tab_Name_Current_Game = Echt_team1 & "vs. " & Echt_team2`

Comment: What is the purpose of the word `array` in this line: `For Each ArrayElement In Current_Tabs array`? It should not compile.

Comment: @99moorem : these are teamnames retrieved from a website.

Comment: @Iturner I het the same problem when I do this

Comment: @mielk is use that to check if worksheet name is found in array. Is does compile but get the error in debug mode when renaming the worksheet

Comment: What is actually in the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `Tab_Name_Current_Game`. 
Add `Dim Tab_Name_Current_Game as String` to your declarations at the top. Then see what happens.

Comment: Same error. It is so weird cause when I set the name to a single string it works. Only when I combine the strings (echt_team1 and echt_team2) the error occurs

Comment: OH! I think I might see the problem. When you combine the strings don't use `+`. Change the `+` to `&`.

Comment: Tried `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it much easier:

```
Public Sub renameSheet()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Tab_Name_Current_Game As String


    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

    'The line below is copied from your code, but I don't like it. 
    'You should pass Echt_team1 and Echt_team2 as input parameters to this Sub.
    Tab_Name_Current_Game = Echt_team1 + "vs. " + Echt_team2 


    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Tab_Name_Current_Game)
    On Error GoTo 0


    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = Tab_Name_Current_Game
    End If


End Sub
```

To make the code more reliable, you can also add this function to your code: [Function to check if sheet name is valid](http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/worksheet/legalSheetName.php), and change this line:

```
        ws.Name = Tab_Name_Current_Game
```

to

```
        ws.Name = legalSheetName(Tab_Name_Current_Game)
```

It will ensure that the name you are trying to assign to a worksheet is not too long and has no illegal characters.